# How to render Django model form drop down manually in the template?

Tags: django, django-forms

Here is my model form

```
class CategoryCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = [
            'nature',
            'name',
            'description',
        ]
```

The field `nature` is a one-to-many foreign field (There could be many categories of the same nature). I know I can render this field in the template using `{{ form.nature }}` but I would like to render the form manually without the help of Django or crispy forms. I have managed to do so for the other fields but don't know how to do it for a `select` field of a model form. I am looking for a solution similar to the following

```
<select class="custom-select custom-select-sm{% if form.nature.errors %} is-invalid{% endif %}" id="{{ form.nature.id_for_label }}" name="{{ form.nature.html_name }}">
    {% for nature in form.nature.objects %}
         <option value="{{ nature.id }}">{{ nature.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: It could be better if you can say that what type of foreign key `nature` is. OneToMany, ManyToMany or what? In this case, I see that you're trying to access to `nature` as a query set. So try this: `form.nature.all`

Comment: @ToanQuocHo  I have updated the question. Tried `form.nature.all`. Didn't work.

Comment: is the nature field values are fixed?

Comment: @ShateelAhmed, it's just an assumption at that moment. If you could provide the model or something more related to the data schema or the relational between the model and `nature` field, it could be easier to come up with an answer

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked

```
<select class="custom-select custom-select-sm{% if form.nature.errors %} is-invalid{% endif %}" id="{{ form.nature.id_for_label }}" name="{{ form.nature.html_name }}">
    {% for id, name in form.fields.nature.choices %}
         <option value="{{ id }}">{{ name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```